# Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function on onkeyup

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm barely new to js but not on php-html web programming, but i confused to js usage.
I was using this js function to compare two input (password checking),
here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/EHUWC/1/

Nothing's wrong there, right?
but it won't work on my own webpage,
here's my code (im using codeigniter):

```
 <div class="centerTitle">Sign Up Form</div>
 <script>
  function chkpassword() {
   var p1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
   var p2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
   if (p1.length > 5) {
    document.getElementById("passwordAlert").style.display = 'none';
    if (p1 === p2) {
     document.getElementById("passwordAlert").style.display = 'none';
     validpass = "yes";
    } else {
      validpass = "no";
      document.getElementById("passwordAlert").style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("passwordAlert").innerHTML = ":( Both passwords must match.";
    }
   } else {
    document.getElementById("passwordAlert").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("passwordAlert").innerHTML = ":( The password must be at least 6 characters long.";
   }
 }
 </script>
 <?php $attributes = array('name' => 'Form1','onsubmit' => 'return validate()');
     echo form_open("visitor/confirm", $attributes);?>
 <table>
 <tr class='signup'>
  <td class='signup1'>Password*</td>
  <td class='signup2'>:</td>
  <td class='signup3'>
   <input id="pass1" onkeyup="chkpassword()" class="signup" type="password" value="" maxlength="20" name="password" />
  </td>
 </tr>
<tr class='signup'>
    <td class='signup1'>Confirm Password*</td>
    <td class='signup2'>:</td>
    <td class='signup3'>
        <input id="pass2" onkeyup="chkpassword()" class="signup" type="password" value="" maxlength="20" name="chkpassword" />
        <div id="passwordAlert"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Daftar">
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

(i'm passing nothing to this view)
if i made mistakes on password input, the div won't come out
then, if i inspect element and look into the console on chrome, it said that the `onkeyup` get `Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function` error
what i've missed?
why it was ok when it runs on jsfiddle?

Comment: the error means that you try to do this: onkeyup(), and onkeyup is a property that should be used like this : .onkeyup = function(){}

Comment: @hjpotter92 eddited! sorry. ;

Comment: in which line it showing the error, paste the full error message.

Comment: @rusln so, i cant use it this way?

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan right when i fill the #pass1 , you know, `onkeyup`.. on line where `<input id="pass2" onkeyup="chkpassword()" class="signup" type="password" value="" maxlength="20" name="chkpassword" />`

Comment: Change the name of that element; does it still throw the error?

Comment: @HenryJahja I asked the error message shown in console

Comment: put the <script> under the form.

Comment: @HenryJahja as far I have seen no error in your code, you just look the page source, may be something else added there..........

Comment: @Sumurai8 you got it! i change the name of chpassword input, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i change the confirm password name (chkpassword) since it was the same name as the js function.

```
<input id="pass2" onkeyup="chkpassword()" class="signup" type="password" value="" maxlength="20" name="chkpassword" />
<input id="pass2" onkeyup="chkpassword()" class="signup" type="password" value="" maxlength="20" name="chkpasswordx" />
```

credit to @Sumurai8